# Is it possible to add a texture to the stroke in Win2d?

Tags: c#, stroke, win2d

The InkDrawingAttributes() properties does not provide any such values.

(C sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Found this by accident, searched like a 100 times for it but the stumbled upon it in the docs.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/custom-rendering-ink?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#ImplementingCustomStrokes